# Why is this spot's callout called "mustang"?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image]

Someone told me that this spot in the rafters above A site on de_nuke is called mustang; however, I have yet to understand why it's called mustang. I know the other side is referred to as heaven, but why is this specific spot referred to as mustang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is refering to the player named Mustang who would camp that exact spot in old cs versions and get crazy sprees.

Comment: Would be great if there was a source for this

Answer (score 0):

This spot is known as "T Rafters" or "Upper" [DE_NUKE Callouts](http://thecsgo.com/de_nuke-callouts/)

"Mustang" might be a closed-knit reference for a particular team. LAN tournaments somtimes position teams' computers close together so a personal reference for callouts can be used by these teams. Think the same way Baseball coaches have hand signs for communicating, but each coach uses different signs to mean different things.